# A subset of three distinct positive integers, each less than 20, is selected. How many subsets will contain exactly one even number?

Tags: combinatorics

I came up with $C(10,2) * 9$, but my book says it's just $C(10,2)$.

The reason why I multiplied my answer by 9 is because we have  $C(10,2)$ for the remaining two odd numbers, and $9$ ways to choose one even number. Why is this not the case?

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: Does that mean my book is wrong?

Comment: Yes, of course. Unless it was meant to ask: "how many... contain exactly one **fixed** even number."

Comment: I see. So if we were asked to find a specific even number and two odd numbers, it would be $C(10,2) * 1 $?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have gotten it. If we multiply by $9$, that means we're **choosing** a particular even number, and here we just want any even number. Does this sound right?

Comment: No. Once you choose two odd numbers out of $10$ odd numbers there are exactly $9$ ways to choose the remaining even number. So your answer in the body looks correct to me. The total number of ways is indeed $9 \times \binom {10} {2}.$